# docker run --ulimit cpu=10 does not kill java process after timeout

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ulimit

I want to make sure the process gets killed after 10 seconds of CPU time. Docker run command accepts the flag `--ulimit cpu=10` that is supposed to do that.

However when I run java command using this, the ulimit setting is ignored. The java process with infinite loop continues even after 10s (actually for minutes until I kill it)
Here is the command I used to test.

```
docker run --rm -i -v /usr/local/src:/classes --ulimit cpu=10 java:8 \
java -cp /classes/ InfiniteLoop
```

Instead of invoking java directly, if I start bash and then run java c, it works as expected.

```
docker run --rm -i -v /usr/local/src:/classes --ulimit cpu=10 java:8 \
bash -c 'date; java -cp /classes/ InfiniteLoop'
```

Why does invoking java program directly does not respect ulimit option?

### **Edit 1:**

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5
```

---

The java program is, InfiniteLoop.java

```
import java.util.*;

class InfiniteLoop {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (long i = 0; i < 1000_000_000_000L; i++) {
      if (i % 1_000_000_000 == 0) {
        System.out.println(new Date() + ", i = " + i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit 2:**
The following doesn't work either. That is, with only java executed in the bash.

```
docker run --rm -i -v /usr/local/src:/classes --ulimit cpu=10 java:8 \
bash -c 'java -cp /classes/ InfiniteLoop'
```

But, adding any noop or ':' command works. Or even an arbitrary word that prints "command not found" also works.

```
docker run --rm -i -v /usr/local/src:/classes --ulimit cpu=10 java:8 \
bash -c ':; java -cp /classes/ InfiniteLoop'
```

and this works too.

```
docker run --rm -i -v /usr/local/src:/classes --ulimit cpu=10 java:8 \
bash -c 'ArbirtraryCommandNotFound; java -cp /classes/ InfiniteLoop'
```

**Edit 3:**
Similar to using the no-op (:), invoking the process with time also makes the process to be killed exactly after the CPU time is exceeded.

```
docker run --rm -i -v /usr/local/src:/classes --ulimit cpu=10 java:8 \
bash -c 'time java -cp /classes/ InfiniteLoop'
```

Comment: This looks suspiciously similar to what has has been reported in a GitHub issue earlier this year: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1905

Comment: Because, it is the same, and I still haven't got the answer. It would be great, if you knew the answer, and can help me understand.

Comment: I'm having hard times to reproduce it since I don't know which Docker version you're using nor do I have access to your Java source files.

Comment: Added the java source code, docker version, etc. Another thing I found, in bash command if I put any other commands before java, then ulimit works, otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: if you run `top`, it should list how much cpu time your java process has taken. An infinite loop printing the date, I would guess, doesn't peg the CPU and would likely require far more clock time than 10 seconds to get to 10 seconds of cpu time.

Comment: @programmerq I checked with top The program consistently took 90+% CPU and had TIME column showed more than 50seconds, until I killed the process.
It also doesn't explain why running a no-op before invoking java works.

Comment: So I can reproduce it now on Docker 1.11.2 but still dunno why. Will keep digging until I find the reason.

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas Thanks.
If it helps, I see the same behavior even when running C++ programs. So, it was nothing specific to java

Comment: @JackDaniels aha! that is a useful information, thanks! I'm investigating with https://github.com/mhausenblas/cinf now to figure if there's something funny going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some [experimenting](https://gist.github.com/mhausenblas/224df8caa9a29175faac71ea026656c6) I re-read the original question and also took into account the fact that it is independent of the type of program being launched, that is, Java, C++, etc.: the reason why it works in the one case (when invoked with `bash -c`) and not when you directly invoke it is that `ulimit` is a [bash built in command](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) and the docs for `docker run` are [not entirely transparent about it](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-ulimits-in-container---ulimit).

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean ulimit will never work when starting any programs other than with bash? It also doesn't explain why 'bash -c' also works only when there are already two commands (even if the first one is an invalid command)?

Comment: Yes, ulimit only works with bash but you can use [cgroups](http://containerz.info/) as a generic solution.

Comment: with cgroups, I can only specify cpu_quota per cpu_period, I want to provide an upper limit on total cpu usage. That aside, I can understand why ulimit will work only in bash, but even in bash it doesn't work all the time. It works only if there are atleast 2 commands, even if the extra command is invalid or when invoked with time.

Comment: I'm not following @JackDaniels you can totally do that with [cpu.cfs_quota_us](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-bwc.txt). The other observation is correct, I think, and just means that the Docker implementation is buggy ;)

Comment: The documentation says,
cpu.cfs_quota_us: the total available run-time within a period (in microseconds)
cpu.cfs_period_us: the length of a period (in microseconds)
When quota exceeds, the process gets throttled, not killed. (Whereas when setting cpu, it gets killed.)

Comment: Right you are. OK, I also checked the other [cpu](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-bwc.txt) cgroups docs but seems the only way to emulate ulimit exactly is using the [setrlimit](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=23618&seqNum=6) syscall directly.