# Cleaning up orphaned docker containers after Jenkins job is terminated

Tags: docker, jenkins

I work at a large organization that runs hundreds of jobs in a shared Jenkins cluster.

My Jenkins job needs to run integration tests against untrusted code running inside Docker containers. I am fearful that that when my Jenkins job gets terminated abruptly (e.g. job aborted or times out) I will be left with orphaned containers.

I have tried https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1905 and `ulimits` does not work for me (this is because [it only works for containers that run `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40846294/14731), and I cannot guarantee that mine will do so).

I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/26351355/14731 but `--lxc-conf` is not a recognized option for Docker for Windows (this needs to run across all platforms supported by docker).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of things, people are handling this outside of docker.

They are adding Jenkins post-build steps that clean up orphaned docker containers on aborted or failed builds.

See Martin Kenneth's [build script](https://bitbucket.org/martinkenneth/machine-tz-2017/src/114f842ce04cac9823e7dd3e0cd5c117bdbba115/Jenkinsfile?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) as an example.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can have a cleanup command in the first and last step of your job, for example, first clean old deads, then rename the existing contailer to old_$jobname and kill it

- `docker container prune -f`
- `docker rename $jobname old$jobname`
- `docker kill old$jobname` do whatever  you need

launch your new container
- `docker run --name $jobname$`

Comment: What happens if my Jenkins job is killed, and is never run again? Point is, I can't guarantee that I will be around long enough to shut down the container myself.

Comment: in that case, run the container with -i (interactive) instead of -d (detached or daemon I guess ) and launch your tests as the command like: 
`docker run -i --name go_web_tests ${JOB_NAME} sh test.sh`
the container will die when process complete, then, if you are worried of dead containers, you can clean up on the next build

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this will work in my case. My unit test depends on multiple containers (e.g. mysql and wordpress) so I can only launch one of them in interactive mode.